# Bash CGI with apache, force apache to finish sending data to browser, without waiting for script completion

Tags: apache, bash, http, cgi

I have a cgi script that runs perfectly on my mac server.  It sends out varied outputs just like any cgi script should.  My problem however, is that sometimes I need the cgi script to run a long task before quitting.  The problem with this however is that the browser then has to wait the long time before it sees the output.  Is there any way to say "this script is not sending any more output" to apache and have it send it out while still allowing the cgi to finish its tasks in the background?

a general outline of my code is:

- script outputs various possible outputs based on query string
- script usually ends
- if a specific query string was sent, run a long piece of code that the user does not need to wait for

Comment: I would think that closing stdout would do it.

Comment: how would one do that in bash?

Comment: `>&-` closes stdout ( `n>&-` closes fd n )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the long task to a jobs queue.

```
echo "your long task" | at now
```

Comment: I don't have the at command installed, I may try it though (MacOsX)

Comment: I found the daemon command.  The command appears to run the specified command in the background, however there is no way to force it to not run as _www (the web server user) which does not have the proper permissions to launch the application needed.  Any suggestions to allow it to run as a full macOsX user or root?

Comment: [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) or [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)

Answer (score 1):

I don't now what you want to get, but probably you need to disable deflate module. 
This module compressing page before send it to browser, so your script must be done. If disabled, then script's output will be printed dynamicly